# How to redraw a particular widget from multiple widget in the widget tree

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter , we are creating a new custom widget for our need,

We have two custom painters to perform painting inside our widget

-First custom painter will perform rectangle drawing and
 another custom painter will perform circle drawing using the paint override method

We have material bottom in the app. When ever button click is performed i have called setState() .

My scenario is to achieve the below requirements,

Need to redraw or call paint method of the second custom painter.
Should not redraw the first custom painter.

How to achieve my scenario???

Comment: Please share the code for reference.

Comment: @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true; Is this the one you are saying about

Comment: Any solution you got for this?